# Singleton pattern - different values of property

Tags: c#, singleton

I have a simple class using singleton pattern :

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyClass()
    { }

    private static MyClass instance;
    private static readonly object locked = new object();

    //Singleton
    public static MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (locked)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new MyClass();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public string Rand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Random().Next(2500).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

But if I do :

```
var instance1 = MyClass.Instance;
var instance2 = MyClass.Instance;
```

`instance1.Rand`and `instance2.Rand` have different values.

Why does my singleton have two different instances and how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

there is difference between Singleton instance which a single instance and accessing the Rand property which create a new random value each time if you want to create the same value each time you have to create a private field or make this in

```
  private string _rand; 

  public static MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (locked)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new MyClass();
                    _rand = return new Random().Next(2500).ToString();

                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

public string Rand {
 get {
     return _rand;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you try to access Rand, it calls the get method, causing it to create a new Random Instance

Instead try this:

```
private string _rand = return new Random().Next(2500).ToString();

public string Rand {
 get {
     return _rand;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the random value everytime `Rand` is read from.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some c# 6 to the mix and using `Lazy` of .NET 4.

```
public class MyClass
        {
            private static Lazy<MyClass> instance = new Lazy<MyClass>(() => new MyClass());

            public static MyClass Instance => instance.Value;

            public string Rand { get; } = (new Random()).Next(2500).ToString();

            private MyClass() { }
        }
```

Edit
For the difference between the 
`public string Rand { get { return (new Random()).Next(2500).ToString(); } }` and `public string Rand { get; } = (new Random()).Next(2500).ToString();`
The first code executes the code in the body of the property (get{ everything in hear }) while the second is executed during the field initialization(A special step that runs before the constructor). This is called Auto-property initializer. And is the same to you writhing this

```
public readonly string rand = (new Random()).Next(2500).ToString();

            public string Rand
            {
                get
                {
                    return rand;
                }
            }
```

For more info you can look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6/

NOTE: Singleton is considered to be an [Antipattern](https://www.microsoft.com/net/tutorials/csharp/getting-started/patterns-antipatterns) so if you can don't use it.

Comment: Why `string Rand { get; } = (new Random()).Next(2500).ToString();` return the same value everytime while `get { return new Random().Next(2500).ToString(); }` does not return the same value ?

Comment: @Azerty123  Singleton is considered to be an [Antipattern](https://www.microsoft.com/net/tutorials/csharp/getting-started/patterns-antipatterns) so if you can don't use it.